# Referring to files in zipfileset which does not exist in ANT

Tags: ant

I want to know if this is possible:

- Referring to files in `zipfileset` which may or may no exist due to build output

how can i handle this in `zipfileset`

Any ideas?

Thanks

Regards

Karthik

Answer (score 2):

Include/exclude works for files, but not directories.
At least as of 1.8.x (which is what I'm using, didn't check 1.6), you can use:

```
<zipfileset dir="something" prefix="" erroronmissingdir="false">
```

to not yield that error.
The "erroronmissingdir" attribute allows a fix for this condition.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem with it.

Here is an example zip (jar) file:

```
$ jar tvf src.zip
     0 Wed Nov 30 11:54:38 GMT 2011 META-INF/
    62 Wed Nov 30 11:54:38 GMT 2011 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Wed Nov 30 11:53:28 GMT 2011 src/
     0 Wed Nov 30 11:57:14 GMT 2011 src/a/
     0 Wed Nov 30 11:53:38 GMT 2011 src/a/exists.txt
     0 Wed Nov 30 11:57:14 GMT 2011 src/a/other.txt
```

Here is an example build file to test the behaviour of zipfileset for existent and non-existent files:

```
<project default="test">

  <target name="test">
    <pathconvert property="found">
      <zipfileset src="src.zip">
        <include name="src/a/not-exists.txt"/>
        <include name="src/a/exists.txt"/>
      </zipfileset>
    </pathconvert>
    <echo message="found: ${found}"/>
    <mkdir dir="extract"/>
    <copy todir="extract">
      <zipfileset src="src.zip">
        <include name="src/a/not-exists.txt"/>
        <include name="src/a/exists.txt"/>
      </zipfileset>
    </copy>
  </target>

</project>
```

Here is the output from this sample:

```
$ ant
Buildfile: C:\tmp\ant\build.xml

test:
     [echo] found: C:\tmp\ant\src.zip:src/a/exists.txt
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\tmp\ant\extract
     [copy] Copying 1 resource to C:\tmp\ant\extract

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
```

**There are no errors from the attempt to access non-existent files.**

And here is the result in the dir files were copied to from the zip:

```
$ find extract/
extract/
extract/src
extract/src/a
extract/src/a/exists.txt
```